# Why doesn't my code fetch new data on every cycle of the loop?

Tags: c, http, get, libcurl

I'm writing [a simple program](https://github.com/omrisim210/chuck) in C using ncurses, cJSON and libcurl that fetches Chuck Norris facts when you press a key and for some reason the fact stays the same no matter how many times it runs.

I believe the problematic code is [here](https://github.com/omrisim210/chuck/blob/master/main.c#L46):

```
for(;;) {
    /* get the json data */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

    /* check for errors */
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",\
        curl_easy_strerror(res));
    } else {
        /*
         * Now, our chunk.memory points to a memory block that is chunk.size
         * bytes big and contains the remote file.
         *
         * Do something nice with it!
         */

        cJSON* root   = cJSON_Parse((char *) chunk.memory);
        char*  joke   = cJSON_GetObjectItem(root, "value")->valuestring;
        printw("Here's a joke:\n %s\n", joke);
        cJSON_Delete(root);
        getch();
    }
}
```

Why does it not work as expected and what is the correct way to write this?

Comment: Do you change memory pointer for parsing new chunk of JSON?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: While you're thinking about how to create a MCVE, here's another thing to think about (and which is hinted about in the comment by @tilz0R): In the second (and all following) iterations of the loop, what is the contents of `chunk`?

Comment: Are you sure you're *fetching* a new "Chuck Norris fact" each time you call `curl_easy_perform`? If you're sure of that, are you sure that your curl callbacks are *writing* the new fact into the chunk each time? It's very hard for people here to help you debug this unless you paste enough code in here for them to see what you fetch each time and how you write it into the chunk. Also: consider using a debugger and finding out for yourself. You might find your bug faster than by asking online.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone, I'll take a look at my callback function (and there's a link to all of my code in the post, where it says "a simple program")